# rabbitmq (AMQP): delete all messages from a queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

There are some questions like mine on SO, but `purge` method is not suitable for me. From AMQP docs:

> Purge a queue.
>       This method removes all messages from a queue which **are not awaiting acknowledgment**.

What if I want to delete really **all** messages even if they are waiting acks? Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way I can think of is to delete a queue (consider messages are not persistent) and create it back :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't delete unacked messages. What you can do is get them back in ready state with basic.recover() or by killing the connection responsible for the unacked messages. After that you can purge the queue.